# Split words & shuffle / jumble letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, split, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle words. I Want to shuffle First with its respective alphabets. Currently it is shuffling First with Second alphabets..

I Want to split words & shuffle "sFtir Seocdn".

```
String.prototype.shuffle = function () {
    var a = this.split(""),
        n = a.length;

    for (var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
    return a.join("");
}


alert("First Second".shuffle());
```

I tried splitting by below code, but then it only splits & shuffles words not letters.

```
var a = this.split(" "),
return a.join(" ");
```

Jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/9L8rs/1/
Pls suggest what should I do.

Comment: You need to call shuffle on the individual words...

Comment: First split with a space, then loop through those results, and split with `string.split('')`. Then do your shuffle and join

Comment: In addition to VisioN's answer, here's a solution keeping everything inside of `shuffle` (so the code using `shuffle` doesn't have to worry about words): http://jsfiddle.net/7hjg4/ . But I guess it depends on how you're expecting to use this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try splitting the incoming String first:

```
String.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    return this.split(" ").map(function(word, i) {
        var a = word.split(""),
            n = a.length;

        for (var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var tmp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = tmp;
        }

        return a.join("");
    }).join(" ");
}

alert("First Second".shuffle());
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9L8rs/5/)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I expect that someone didn't enjoy your `forEach`-like use of `map` method.

Comment: Thanks @VisioN, I updated the code to make it more 'mappy' :)

Answer (score 6):

Just split the string into words and shuffle the letters in words separately:

```
"First Second".split(' ').map(function(w) { return w.shuffle(); }).join(' ');
```

Here [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (*[polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) may be applied for old browsers*) methods can help.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9L8rs/2/

Answer (score 1):

I just added a function shuffleWords that split on words and call your shuffle function on each of them. ex. `a[i] = a[i].shuffle();`

```
String.prototype.shuffleWords = function () {
    var a = this.split(" "),
        n = a.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = a[i].shuffle();
    }
    return a.join(" ");
}
```

See your updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9L8rs/3/)